# Error al definir char

Tags: c, preprocesador

Tengo este código simple de una Header File y me da error al definir esto:

```
typedef char Cadena[N];
```

y mi código es este :

```
 /* cadenas.h */


#ifndef CADENAS_H_
#define CADENAS_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 129;

typedef enum{FALSO,CIERTO} Logico;
typedef char Cadena[N];

int buscaCaracter(const Cadena cad,char c);
Logico esPalindromo(const Cadena cad);


#endif /* CADENAS_H_ */
```

Soy principiante en C , y es un código bastante simple pero no sé porqué al definir el type char me da error de sintaxis.

Comment: hola @Dioni que error te da?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al [compilar](https://ideone.com/rwknIs) tu cabecera me da este error:

```
prog.c:7:14: error: expected ']' before ';' token
 #define N 129;
              ^
```

Entonces la solución sería sacar ese  `;` del `#define`

```
#define N 129
```

*Ten en cuenta que las directivas de pre-procesador (como #define, #ifndef, etc) no llevan ; al final ya que no es sintaxis C o C++*

Comment: Muchas gracias no lo sabía. Saludos

Comment: Excelente, para eso está la comunidad, no dudes en preguntar.